# Sorting KML placemarks alphabetically using XSLT 3.0

Tags: xml, xslt, kml, saxon, xslt-3.0

I am trying to sort alphabetically Placemark elements in a KML document. The document contains multiple Folder elements which I do not want to reorder. I only need to sort the Placemarks inside each Folder.

Sample input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>Test</name>
    <Folder>
      <name>Zulu</name>
      <Placemark>
        <name>Bravo</name>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>
            20,30,0
          </coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
      <Placemark>
        <name>Alfa</name>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>
            10,20,0
          </coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
    </Folder>
    <Folder>
      <name>Yankee</name>
      <Placemark>
        <name>Delta</name>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>
            40,50,0
          </coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
      <Placemark>
        <name>Charlie</name>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>
            30,40,0
          </coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
    </Folder>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

Expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>Test</name>
    <Folder>
      <name>Zulu</name>
      <Placemark>
        <name>Alfa</name>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>
            10,20,0
          </coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
      <Placemark>
        <name>Bravo</name>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>
            20,30,0
          </coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
    </Folder>
    <Folder>
      <name>Yankee</name>
      <Placemark>
        <name>Charlie</name>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>
            30,40,0
          </coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
      <Placemark>
        <name>Delta</name>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>
            40,50,0
          </coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
    </Folder>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

I have tried the following XSLT 3.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output name="xml"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" />

  <xsl:template match="Folder">
    <xsl:perform-sort select="Folder/Placemark">
      <xsl:sort select="name" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
    </xsl:perform-sort>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It doesn't do anything. I am trying to use XSLT 3.0 since it is the latest spec. I am using Saxon to run the transform (in case it matters):

```
java -jar Saxon-HE-10.0.jar -s:source.kml -xsl:sort.xsl -o:output.kml
```

If someone knows how to do this with XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, I'll take it but I'd prefer XSLT 3.0.

Cheers

Comment: A stylesheet set up with `xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"` is probably doing that, copying everything through. So what does "It doesn't do anything" mean, do you get no output or the input as the output? The other problem is the default namespace, that is the FAQ, although with Saxon 10 there should be a new setting to deal with it. Will need to check the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very basic approach would be defining a namespace on the `xsl:stylesheet` element and using it (the "select" expression has been wrong):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <xsl:output name="xml"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" />

  <xsl:template match="kml:Folder">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="* except kml:Placemark" />
      <xsl:perform-sort select="kml:Placemark">
        <xsl:sort select="kml:name" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
      </xsl:perform-sort>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The sorting works but I am loosing the Folder elements. The Placemark elements end up directly under the parent Document element with my example input.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot the `xsl:copy`'s. Now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

From Saxon 10 on, to have e.g. `match="Folder"` match elements in the namespace `http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2`, you can use the command line option `-ns:http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2`, see http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xsl/commandline/.

Of course in XSLT 2 and later you can also set `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"` on the `xsl:stylesheet` element.

The `perform-sort` seems to have the wrong select with `Folder/Placemark`, I think it should be `Placemark`, but the task of only sorting the `Placemark` elements is probably not solved the way you have set up the template anyway. The complexity of a solution depends on the possible complexity of the input, whether the `Placemark` elements can be mixed with other children or not; if you know all other elements will be before the Placemark children then it should suffice to use

```
<xsl:template match="Folder">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="* except Placemark, sort(Placemark, (), function($p) { $p/name })"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

in XSLT 3 and with Saxon 10 HE or earlier versions of Saxon but PE or EE.

If the Placemark elements are all adjacent then

```
<xsl:template match="Folder">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent=". instance of element(Placemark)">
            <xsl:apply-templates
              select="if (current-grouping-key())
                      then sort(current-group(), (), function($p) { $p/name })
                      else current-group()"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

should suffice.